# How do you paginate output from an aggregate pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo

I am trying to paginate a series of posts for a blog. I have a pipeline that outputs posts sorted nicely and I'm trying to use facet to paginate the results. Skip and limit are working, but when I pass a page number from a url with http://localhost:5000/?page=4 into the the pipeline, nothing changes. I still just get the first 5 (or however many I set the limit to) posts

```
def posts_with_comment_count(page):

    pipeline = [
        {"$lookup": {
            "from": "comment",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "post_id",
            "as": "comment_count"
        }},
        {"$addFields": {
            "comment_count": {"$size": "$comment_count"}
        }},
        {"$sort": {"_id": -1}}, 
        {'$facet': { 
            "metadata": [{"$count": "total"}, {"$addFields": {"page": int(page)}}],
            "data": [{"$skip": 0}, {"$limit": 5}] 
            }}

    ]
    posts = list(mongo.db.posts.aggregate(pipeline))
    return posts


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
@app.route("/index")
def home():

    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)   
    data = posts_with_comment_count(page)

    def posts():
     for post in data:
        return post['data']

    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts())
```

Comment: change skip-limit with 
 {$skip: (pageNo - 1) * 5},{$limit: 5}
here 5 is no of documents per page

Comment: @sushantmehta Yes!, thank you so much. That fixed it. I know I had to get (pageno -1) * 5 in there somewhere.